# How to get logs using Graph API for invalid usernames attempt?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to get logs for invalid username attempts using Graph API, by calling this endpoint:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns

For example, I'm sending a request to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token" to generate a token using grant_type=password, but I'm using a username from a non-existent user, that does not exist in our tenant. Microsoft returns to me:

```
AADSTS50034: The user account {EmailHidden} does not exist in the domain.com directory. To sign into this application, the account must be added to the directory.\r\nTrace ID: {GUID}\r\nCorrelation ID: {GUID}\r\nTimestamp: {TIMESTAMP}
```

But this specific error does not show up on:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=correlationId eq '{GUID}'`.

This metric is important for us to know if the users are using our system correctly.

Can I use another Graph endpoint to extract this information or it's a limitation from AzureAD?

Thanks and appreciate all kind of advice.

Answer (score 1):

I have one Azure AD application named `GraphAug` with **API permission** as below:

[image]

When I tried to generate access token by passing username from a **non-existent** user via Postman, I too got **same error**:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:appId
grant_type:password
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
username:sridevi@Mxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password:xxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I ran below query in [**Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) by filtering with **`correlation_id`** and got **blank** results same as you:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=correlationId eq '{GUID}'
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, you can **only** fetch successful and failed sign-in attempts of **existing** users in that tenant by running this query: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns

When I tried to generate access token by passing username from a **existing** user with wrong password via Postman, I got **different** error saying invalid username or password:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:appId
grant_type:password
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
username:sri@Mxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password:xxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can extract this log information of **existing** user by running below query in [**Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), filtering with **`correlation_id`**:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=correlationId eq '{GUID}'
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where the **logs** are same as below:

[image]

Alternatively, you can raise **support ticket** with Microsoft and share **`correlation_id`** with them to get more details of that **specific error** logs.

Comment: Do you think graph was designed like this? to not catch failed username attemps on auditLogs? or do you think it's a bug? i did the exactly same test as you did